# scraping navigation pages using screen-scraper

Tags: web-scraping

I am new to screen-scraper. I am scraping a website called "www.uspto.gov".

These are the two links:

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=0&f=S&l=50&d=PTXT&OS=%22social+networking%22&RS=%22social+networking%22&Query=%22social+networking%22&TD=6908&Srch1=%22social+networking%22&NextList2=Next+50+Hits

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=0&f=S&l=50&d=PTXT&OS=%22social+networking%22&RS=%22social+networking%22&Query=%22social+networking%22&TD=6908&Srch1=%22social+networking%22&NextList3=Next+50+Hits

Now we can see from these urls that there is no direct parameter for next page like "page = 2". Instead of that I need to take the whole url into variable and then somehow change the parameters which are called as NextList2 and NextList3.

Can anyone help me by providing the solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scraping next page links using screen-scraper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752742/scraping-next-page-links-using-screen-scraper)

Answer (score 0):

Pagination like this is not uncommon. What I would do is extract the total results from:

```
Hits 51 through 100 out of 6908
```

And make a script to:

```
total = Integer.parseInt(dataRecord.get("TOTAL"));
perPage = 100
pages = total/perPage;
if (tota%perPage>0)
    pages++;

for (i=2; i<=pages; i++)
{
    param = "NextList" + String.valueOf(i);
    session.log("Scraping " + param);
    session.setv("NEXT_PARAM", param);
    session.scrapeFile("Next search results");
}
```